# Force test of move constructor?

Tags: c++, move-semantics

I'm implementing move construct/assign operations for an object that points to some data on the heap.

I'm testing move construct/assign and copy construct/assign, everything builds and all work except for move construct. (Move assignment does work).

I can't seem to get the debugger to trip, the move constructor code is not being reached.

I'm sure there's something simple I am missing?

The move constructor...

```
//...

HeapBuffer (HeapBuffer&& other)                     // move
    : data {other.data},
      size {other.size}
{
    assert(false);              // hmm can't seem to debug to here in testing :(
    other.data = nullptr;
    other.size = 0;
}

//...
```

The testing function...

```
ado::HeapBuffer<2048> makeHeapBuffer2048()  // test move semantics
{
    ado::HeapBuffer<2048> hb2048;
    hb2048[777] = 123.0f;
    return hb2048;
}
```

The calling test...

```
beginTest ("HeapBuffer move constructor");  // hmmm can't seem to get to the move constructor,
                                            // strange because all the others work!?!?
{
    ado::HeapBuffer<2048> hb {makeHeapBuffer2048()};

    expectEquals (hb[777], 123.0f);
}
```

I will add that if I change the move constructor to...

```
HeapBuffer (HeapBuffer&&) = delete;
```

...the build fails at the expected point (i.e. tripped by the test).

Comment: elision should probably occurs

Comment: Search for "c++ copy elision".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

elision should probably occurs, you may try:

```
ado::HeapBuffer<2048> moved;
moved[777] = 123.0f;
ado::HeapBuffer<2048> hb{std::move(moved)};

expectEquals (hb[777], 123.0f);
```

Comment: Perfect thanks, I've added `moved[777] = 123.0f` so the assertion expectEquals() works.